# Displaying percentages in tiny stacked bar chart segments

Tags: info-visualisation, color, charts

[image: My stacked bar chart]

Specifically, how to handle cases where a (stacked bar chart's) segment has a small value, leaving little visual space for displaying data inside that segment.

For example, if the pink segment was 3%, the edges of the pink rectangle would overlap with the number inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always write the label alongside.

But really, you shouldn't be relying on the image itself as the only way convey that information. For accessibility reasons you should have textual, descriptive content to give this information. So supplement the image with a table with textual breakdown of the results.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f77ksE.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>